# Check and Multiply selected numbers from two spinners

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have created two spinners  containing numbers.

```
Spinner weightSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Weightspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DrinksActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weight));
        myAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        weightSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter5);
```

This is one of the spinners and here is the array that the spinner contains.

```
<string-array name="weight">
        <item>6350.29</item> <!--1st-->
        <item>12700.6</item><!--2st-->
        <item>19050.9</item><!--3st-->
        <item>25401.2</item><!--4st-->
        <item>31751.5</item><!--5st-->
        <item>38101.8</item><!--6st-->
        <item>44452.1</item><!--7st-->
        <item>50802.3</item><!--8st-->
        <item>57152.6</item><!--9st-->
        <item>63502.9</item><!--10st-->
        <item>69853.2</item><!--11st-->
        <item>76203.5</item><!--12st-->
        <item>82553.8</item><!--13st-->
        <item>88904.1</item><!--14st-->
        <item>95254.4</item><!--15st-->
        <item>101605</item><!--16st-->
        <item>107955</item><!--17st-->
        <item>114305</item><!--18st-->
        <item>120656</item><!--19st-->
        <item>127006</item><!--20st-->
        <item>133356</item><!--21st-->
        <item>139706</item><!--22st-->
        <item>146057</item><!--23st-->
        <item>152407</item><!--24st-->
        <item>158757</item><!--25st-->
        <item>165108</item><!--26st-->
        <item>171458</item><!--27st-->
        <item>177808</item><!--28st-->
        <item>184159</item><!--29st-->
        <item>190509</item><!--30st-->
    </string-array>
```

I also have another spinner containing numbers and I would like the selected number from this spinner to be multiplied by another spinner containing numbers when a button is selected. Here is the XML code for the button.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/AddDrink"
        android:textSize="@dimen/TxtSize"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/LargeTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Conversion"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Conversion" />
```

I would like to know how i can do this from java code. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a select event listener to either spinner?

Comment: no I haven't added an event listener yet

Comment: do you want the result every time the selection on a spinner changes or when you press a certain button?

Comment: I want the changes to be made after the button has been selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiplying the two numbers in spinners, first you need to get the values in them (will be as `String`), convert it to a suitable Number Datatype (best to use the `BigDecimal` since you are using decimals too) and then multiply them.

```
button.setOnClickListener(                 //onButtonClick
       new Button.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v)
              {
                  //Get selected (shown) value in Spinners and store them in String variables
                  String string1 = Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                  String string2 = Spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                 //Assign these values to BigDecimal variables
                  BigDecimal num1 = new BigDecimal(string1);
                  BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal(string2);

                  //Perform your operation
                  num1.multiply(num2);

                  //Since you haven't told what the usage of the result is, I'll leave it to you
                  //To get value of result (num1) do --> num1.toString();
        }
});
```

Comment: How can you multiply this with decimal number like this

Comment: num1.multiply(num2).multiply("568.261");

Comment: Um, why are you trying to multiply again with 568.261? If you do ned to multiply it to num1, store it in another BigDecimal and then multiply. The syntax you are using above is wrong. 

BigDecimal.multiply() has the following syntax: 

**public BigDecimal multiply(BigDecimal multiplicand)**